# Azure DevOps - npm invisible

Tags: npm, azure-devops, newman, postman-collection-runner

I have a strange problem with a release pipeline in Azure DevOps.

I have two tasks:

1) Install packages

2) Run npm using the above packages

All seems to be easy so what I do is:

1) Command line task

```
npm install -g mkdirp 1.0.3
npm install -g newman
npm install -g newman-reporter-junitfull
```

2) PowerShell task

```
   $(newman run $collection -e $environment --env-var "x=$(x)" -r junit --reporter-junit-export $resultFile)
```

This all worked fine until today. I tried a lot, but nothing works.

The error I have is:

> newman : The term 'newman' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program.  Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Did anyone have a similar issue?

Comment: Is there the possibility to join these two tasks in an only one powershell task?

Comment: It is but the question is why this is not working ? ;(

Comment: Could you provide the full build log?
Also, there's a dedicated npm-Task (instead of the cli-task). Maybe swaping those would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran above npm install scripts in a Command line task, and found only the first npm install command got executed. And my following powershell task to run newman command failed with above error message too. You can check the log of Command line task to see if it is the same issue.

If you want to report this issue, you can report a problem [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

The workaround i found is to run the npm install commands in a Powershell task too, do not use Command line task. Then the npm install commands will all get executed and the following powershell task can run successfully.

Or you can separate above three npm install commands into three Command line tasks to install them separately, which will make sure the newman library is installed.